# Add field to drf serializer dynamically

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have an API endpoint that return a list of objects of one of my models.
I have a very trivial serializer that currently returns all the model fields.

What I need now is to add to this serializer another field which is calculated by applying a logic on one of the model field and another data structure that is also calculated dynamicly - but should be calculated only once for each call to the API.

What is the way to supply this structure to the serializer for every API call but not for every object the serializer returns?

My ModelViewSet (without the extra field) is quite trivial:

```
class MyModelViewset(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeModelSerializer
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some suggestions on how you can achieve this:

- To calculate something only once and use it in the serializer you should add it to the serializer [context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context).
- You can create [@property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) in your `SomeModel` class and it can be exposed via serializer fields as read only. Django has also [@cached_property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) so that value is only calculated once and persist as long as the instance does
- You can use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) field if you want to calculate something (you have access the serializer context in there).

Just a quick example on how to use this.

```
class MyModelViewset(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeModelSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context['my_value'] =  [] # calculate something here, you have access to self.request
        return context

class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    my_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel

    def get_my_data(self, obj):
        # you have access to self.context['my_value']
        # you have access to obj.some_property
        return my_data
```